# How can I simulate/mock/bypass a JEE6 container managed login?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm using JEE6 security annotations `@RolesAllowed("Admin")` and a programmatic login:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
request.login(loginUser.getUserName(), loginUser.getPassword());
```

However, for testing, I'd like to be able to 'simulate' a user login, and fool the app that a user logged in, without actually executing the above code. `request.login(...)` will ping the container for a login, I just want to tell the container that foo user has logged in and there is no need to check the password. I really don't want a solution that involves writing a login module or changing the settings of the entire container.

Thanks guys!

EDIT #1: What appserver am I using?

I'm using GlassFish 3.1.1. However, if possible, I'd like a solution that is 'container independent' using any available JEE6 api.

EDIT #2: Mr. Balus (a well regarded expert) is unaware of any api-neutral way bypassing the actual login. I supposed I could write my own "Yes-Man" login module, but I'm curious if anyone knows how to bypass the restriction specifically in the GlassFish environment.

Thanks!

EDIT #3: To anyone who finds this question later, I'm switched to Apache Shiro. I've used Spring Security in the past, but it's overkill for this app.

Comment: What app. server/container are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no API-provided facility for that. You could create a [`Filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) which checks a certain VM argument or environment variable or even a JNDI variable and then does the login automagically.

E.g.

```
String login = System.getProperty("development.login");

if (login != null && request.getRemoteUser() == null) {
    String[] nameAndPassword = login.split(":"); // Assuming "name:password".
    request.login(nameAndPassword[0], nameAndPassword[1]);
}
```

Comment: well... dang. What about a non-api facility in Glassfish?

Comment: None comes to mind. You could also consider to create a cookie based "Remember me" feature (which your webapp's endusers could ultimately also benefit from). It's only a little more work and requires you to really understand the security implications (or you might want to look for 3rd party frameworks like Spring Security). The above filter example is really easy. Just set a VM argument in dev environment. I've even seen approaches where the request remote addr is been tested instead (which I personally don't trust).

Comment: I've used SpringSecurity heavily in the past... I'm trying to just do a pure JEE app, but it looks like there are a lot of shortcomings with security. :(

Comment: That's why everyone reinvents container managed security. It allows almost no fine grained control. Which may be a Good Thing at its own though.

Comment: Are you a member of any of the JEE7 expert groups?

Comment: No, I am not, but I frequently report bugs/enhancements, especially to JSF.